# How to show a block on user/uid but not on user/login and user/registration?

Tags: 7, blocks

I have public profiles for my users at `/users/1` etc and show blocks on that page with the setting "Only the listed pages" of "user*".

Now those blocks also appear on `user/login` and `user/registration` pages.

How can I exclude blocks from those 2 pages?

Otherwise I'll probably use the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module to have the user profiles at `/profile/...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the PHP module, and use this for block visibility settings:

```
<?php
return (bool) menu_get_object('user');
?>
```

Comment: thanks! For future reference, this page lists more snippet examples: http://drupal.org/node/134425#comment-834545

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module here.

> Context allows you to manage contextual conditions and reactions for
>   different portions of your site. You can think of each context as
>   representing a "section" of your site. For each context, you can
>   choose the conditions that trigger this context to be active and
>   choose different aspects of Drupal that should react to this active
>   context.

Comment: that's a good idea, didn't think about context. I got the block to show up based on the context but the weights don't seem to work. The block always shows on the bottom, no matter what the weights are.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to answer your question ***without PHP in the block settings***  (as suggested in another answer), and without using the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module: you can use the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module for this. Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless.
>
> Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
>
> Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
>
> What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to making [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) "***check the path of the current page***" (so that the block is only shown on your pages with a path that **starts with** "`user/`", but not on those pages that have a path **ending with** "`/login`" or "`/registration`").

For an illustration of how to use this module, refer to my answer to "[How to stop a Views block from displaying to admins, such as user/1?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109984/how-to-stop-a-views-block-from-displaying-to-admins-such-as-user-1/193173#193173)". It includes a Rules Component (in Rules export format), which you should replace by this variation of it to make it match your specific question):

```
{ "rules_block_visibility_show_on_selected_member_pages" : {
    "LABEL" : "Show block on selected member pages",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "module" : { "label" : "Module", "type" : "text" },
      "delta" : { "label" : "Delta", "type" : "text" },
      "result" : { "label" : "Result", "type" : "boolean", "parameter" : false }
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "AND" : [
          { "text_matches" : {
              "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
              "match" : "user\/",
              "operation" : "starts"
            }
          },
          { "NOT text_matches" : {
              "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
              "match" : "\/login",
              "operation" : "ends"
            }
          },
          { "NOT text_matches" : {
              "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
              "match" : "\/registration",
              "operation" : "ends"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "result" ], "value" : "1" } } ],
    "PROVIDES VARIABLES" : [ "result" ]
  }
}
```